# Editing a .dgb vector file on Qgis 2.8

Tags: qgis

I have a *.dgb file on landcover (vector format). I am however battling with trying to edit this file. None of the edit tools are active. I have changed the file to not read only. 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Vundla! Don't think I came across a _.dgb_ file before. Do you perhaps mean **.gdb**?